# Bind selenium to a specific IP - Possible?

Tags: selenium, ip, bind, ip-address

Like many, we start selenium server via the following command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar
```

What we found is that this opens selenium up on 0.0.0.0:4444

```
Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444

[USER @ BOX ~]# netstat -na | grep LISTEN | grep 4444
tcp        0      0 :::4444                     :::*                        LISTEN
```

Is there any way to bind selenium to a specific ip (localhost)?

Thanks.

Comment: Please mark as correct one of the answers that has `-host 192.168.1.100` it is now available on selenium >= 2.40.0

Answer (score 9):

Use the following command

```
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -host 192.168.1.100
```

where 192.168.1.100 is the IP address of the host

Comment: this does not work. selenium is started up on 0.0.0.0:4444 regardless.

Comment: This works for me. The command line output still says 'connect on '127.0.0.1:4444' but it looks like I'm able to connect using the host parameter (in my case '10.0.0.179').

Comment: Retornam, the test for whether this works is not to visit the IP specified on the command line, but to visit all the system's *other* IP addresses to see that they *don't* work. When I specify `-host 127.0.0.1`, I can still connect to the server from another computer using the server's external IP address, and that's not supposed to happen.

Comment: @RobKennedy things have changed since I answered this close to a year ago.

Comment: Aside: I'm trying to use selenium grid mode, and using the `-host` setting on the node does affect the IP address for the node reported to the hub, which is a way around the problem I'm having of the hub not being able to connect back to node at the non-routable private address it gives by default with my network configuration.

Comment: Actually if you check the java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -h command you can see the help menu of the Selenium RC server, You realize that there is no -host command at selenium server RC command list.

Comment: I tried this, but when I open showmyip by the browser using selenium again it shows the main ip, not specified by --host parameter.

Answer (score 5):

This is not the correct way of handling this problem but its a way

So what this will do is just drop any connection on port 4444 from any outside source. You can test this by first going to page

start server like this

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -host 127.0.0.1 -port 4444
```

verify everything is working

```
http://yourexternalip:4444/wd/hub/
```

the page will load. if your server is running properly.

Dispatch the commands

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4444 -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4444 -j DROP
```

then reload the page. the webpage will no longer be accessible (because you are accessing from external IP)

your new accessible URL is now

```
http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/
```

which should be working

Again this is more of a band-aid to a greater problem and doing this will not force you to change any source code and still keeping a secure system

Answer (score 2):

This will be possible by adding the "-host 192.168.1.100" parameter, provided you have this fix in your version:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=71c5e231f442

(That fix isn't included in the available binaries at the time of writing so you will have to build your own from source.)

Comment: Hey @Steltek, do you know if the fix is included in selenium 2.40.0? http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.40/

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem with the Hub. So my Hub is pointing toward some other IP address when I tried to UP the hub, but when I check my IP address it was different on my local system. To overcome the problem I just tried the following code and it works.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar -host 192.XXX.X.XX -role hub
```

And my hub was registered to my local machine IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You could run `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar` on a remote machine

and then in your selenium scripts define your webdriver to run remotely.

In ruby you could do it this way

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => "http://specific_ip_of_remotemachine:4444", :desired_capabilities => firefox)
```

is this what you are looking for?

Comment: nope, not what we are looking for. we want to bind the selenium listener (default port 4444) to a specific ip, instead of all the ips on our server.