# Java Selenium bind different Firefox instances to different ip adresses

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I would need to bind 2 different Firefox instances (launched from the same Java process, using Selenium webdriver) to link on 2 different IP adresses (1 from the cable connection and the other from the wireless connection).

While the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607806/bind-selenium-to-a-specific-ip-possible) indicates how to do it at JVM start, it doesn't solve it for new Firefox instances during JVM runtime: any hint would be welcome!

Many thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Tom
To the best of my knowledge this cannot be done because the Firefox Selenium plugin (a .xpi file) is the one that is responsible for spinning off a server component from within the firefox browser. I guess the firefox plugin that does this basically binds itself to using local host. I am not aware of any mechanism wherein we can pass on the IP to which it needs to bind itself rather than using "localhost"