# Making selenium webdriver accessible from the internet

Tags: perl, selenium

I want to run a Perl script which deploys [`Selenium::Remote::Driver`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver) to fetch data from a web site relying heavily on JavaScript. The Perl script and the Selenium WebDriver should run on different machines (client and server, respectively).

I fired up Selenium WebDriver on the server using

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run -e /dev/stdout java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/opt/gecko/geckodriver -jar /opt/selenium/selenium.jar
```

Xvfb has already been started.

The WebDriver reports being properly started and appears in the process list

```
root      6830  6800  7 18:17 pts/0    00:00:01 java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/opt/gecko/geckodriver -jar /opt/selenium/selenium.jar
```

The process is listening at port 4444

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 6830
tcp6       0      0 :::4444                 :::*                    LISTEN      6830/java
```

I then tried to configure the firewall to accept connects from the client machine according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607806/bind-selenium-to-a-specific-ip-possible)

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4444 -s <client-ip> -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4444 -j DROP
```

The Perl script

```perl
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;;

$sel = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new;
$sel->get("http://example.com");
print $sel->get_page_source();
$sel->quit;
```

This works properly when run locally on the server, and returns the desired data.

But when run on the client machine, with a modified constructor

```
$sel = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new( remote_server_addr => '<server-ip>');
```

it refuses to work

> Selenium server did not return proper status at /Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 401.

Issuing a telnet command on the client to check the server's WebDriver port

```
telnet <server-ip> 4444
Trying <server-ip>...
```

Indicates that the port is not open.

What am I missing out?

```
ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5015907 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5015907 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1434694690 (1.3 GiB)  TX bytes:1434694690 (1.3 GiB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: ::2/128 Scope:Compat
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17549498 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18398702 errors:0 dropped:111 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:11881977702 (11.0 GiB)  TX bytes:4577577462 (4.2 GiB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:178.254.xxx.xxx  P-t-P:178.254.xxx.xxx  Bcast:178.254.xxx.xxx  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1

venet0:1  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:178.254.xxx.xxx  P-t-P:178.254.xxx.xxx  Bcast:178.254.xxx.xxx  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Comment: *"The Perl script and the Selenium WebDriver should run on different machines (client and server, respectively)"* The Perl program and the Selenium process are not client and server. The web site is the server; Selenium WebDriver  is an HTTP client; and the Perl program simply controls its behaviour. Running Selenium on a different system from your Perl application makes the whole thing unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: Is the system behind a NAT device? You'll need to configure port-forwarding on the gateway device if so.

Comment: Maybe iptables doesn't play well with tcp6?

Comment: @Borodin: "Running Selenium on a different system from your Perl application makes the whole thing unnecessarily difficult." - This is something which evolves inevitably from the clients requirements and his system's restrictions. If I could run both systems on the same machine I would do it. ;-)

Comment: @stevieb: the machine hosting the Webdriver is a VPS, I do not know much about the network configuration the provider set up. Is there a way to find this out technically without having to consult the hotline, which is often time consuming with this vendor?

Comment: @ysth: Is this a question or a suggestion? ;-) I am not an expert in firewalls/networks. Maybe You can explain this in more depth. And: if You can pinpoint the problem, please make a suggestion how to solve it. THX.

Comment: @ysth Good catch on the v6 there, I completely overlooked that. OP, on the server you're trying to connect to, can you please update your question with the output of `ipconfig` (for any IPv4 or IPv6 addresses, replace the last half of them with `xxx` as to masquerade your real address).