# Force selenium-webdriver to bind to localhost

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

When using `selenium-webdriver`, something attempts to bind to a port, listening for connections from the unspecified IPv6/IPv4 host (`::` / `0.0.0.0`). This triggers a firewall message.

I'd like to avoid this firewall message by forcing whatever this is to bind only to `localhost`, but I can't find any clues about what this server is or how to configure it.

Example code which replicates the issue:

```javascript
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
setTimeout(() => {
  driver.quit();
}, 10000);
```

On macOS, this shows the prompt:

> Do you want the application “node” to accept incoming network connections?

Obviously choosing "deny" still allows the tests to run (since everything is local anyway), and after selecting this option the OS remembers the choice until Node is updated, but I'd like to lock-down the test so that this isn't an issue.

What is causing this? How can I configure it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Selenium Standalone Server](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2) and [bind it to a specific IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607806/bind-selenium-to-a-specific-ip-possible). Additionally you can [disable IPv6 addresses lookup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html).

1. Launch Selenium Standalone Server like:

   ```
   java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.x.jar -host 10.20.30.40
   ```
2. Amend your webdriver initialization code to explicitly set the Selenium Server address like:

   ```
   const driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').usingServer('http://10.20.30.40:4444/wd/hub').build();
   ```

   replace this `10.20.30.40` with the IP address of your choice (the IP address or alias must exist on the system where you run the test)

References:

- [Selenium with JavaScript - The Standalone Selenium Server](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html)
- [Connecting Selenium Hubs to Cloud Server](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/DAL/Connecting+Selenium+Hubs+to+Cloud+Server)

Comment: Following those instructions does indeed prevent both Nodejs and Java from triggering a firewall prompt (I used `-host localhost`). Am I correct in thinking that without `usingServer`, the nodejs library launches its own (non-java) server? (I say non-java because the firewall prompt is for node, not java). Is it possible to configure this fall-back server? I'd prefer to keep the simplicity of fewer moving parts and no java dependency while still binding only to localhost.

Comment: Hmm, looking through the code for what that option is affecting, I see that omitting the option does not launch a standalone server, but instead (ultimately) affects this branch https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-4.0.0-alpha-1/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js#L690, and chasing it deeper looks like it is supposed to work already: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-4.0.0-alpha-1/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js#L240 https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-4.0.0-alpha-1/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js#L238

Comment: (I suspect what I'm observing is a bug?)