# Selenium server HUB setting up to specific IP and PORT

Tags: java, selenium, ip, port, selenium-grid

Can somebody explain me please how to properly set up Selenium server HUB to specific IP and PORT? I found this [Bind selenium to a specific IP - Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607806/bind-selenium-to-a-specific-ip-possible) but I am not sure what is the proper IP as it would be safe. Every solution uses different IP 192..... 127.... Is it important which one I choose or it does not matter?

I mean it is necessary if is necessary to restart HUB as the code will refer to the same HUB IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important in the sense how do you want this hub to be reachable; only from the same machine, or from others too.
The question is not that much selenium, but rather networking one; so here are the three most common options:

- use `127.0.0.1` - a.k.a. "localhost", the loopback interface - the hub will be reachable only from the same machine, and no other. By definition the loopback interface is nonroutable in the networks - all packets are staying within the same host, thus - no one else can send a packet to it (because their packet will not leave their machine). In short, the hub and the selenium client must be on the same machine for this scenario.
- `192.168.x.y`, `10.x.y.z` or just an ip address `a.b.c.d` - the selenium hub process will bind to this address, and as long as it is reachable any client will be able to communicate with it (vs just local when using the loopback). If the server has multiple network interfaces, the hub is going to be accessible only on the one you specified.
- the `0.0.0.0` - that is not an actual ip address (cannot be assigned, and used only for specific/special cases like DHCP), but used to communicate to the OS the process wants to bind to *all* available ip addresses on the host. So if it has 2 network interfaces, one with ip `1.2.3.4` and the other `192.168.100.57`, the hub will be reachable on both of them (plus localhost, `127.0.0.1` this is also an address). This by the way is the default behavior of Selenium Hub (and most server services).

So pick one depending on your needs - limiting to local connections only, to a specific interface if you have a few, or to all of them.

By the way, the question you link to is a little bit different - apparently when it was raised, Selenium had a bug that the binding to a specific address didn't work, it was always using the `0.0.0.0`option.

Answer (score -1):

I use the following command to start Hub (very useful when system is connected to VPN):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub -host <IP Address> -port <port number>
```

Answer (score -2):

Generally, you would like to set up the *Selenium Grid HUB* on the `localhost` and to use a specific **PORT** you can use the following command:

- Start the Selenium Grid Server (on port `5786`):

  ```
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub -port 5786
  ```
- Console logs:

  ```
  20:25:31.123 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0'
  20:25:31.139 INFO [GridLauncherV3$2.launch] - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 5786
  2020-02-10 20:25:31.998:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1573ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
  20:25:32.706 INFO [Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
  20:25:32.707 INFO [Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://192.168.1.125:5786/grid/register/
  20:25:32.708 INFO [Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://192.168.1.125:5786/wd/hub
  ```
- Now, you can access the *Selenium Grid HUB* accessing the url `http://localhost:5786/grid/console` as follows:

[image: GridHubConsole]

Comment: The answer is fundamentally wrong - there is no host parameter passed at all, and the server is **not** started on localhost. And generally, you *do not* want to start a selenium hub on localhost only - that defies its purpose for distributed computing.